# How to correct React Portal error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-portal

im having an issue getting react portals working. I dont understand why I am receiving error message portal id is not DOM element that is clearly a valid DOM element.

I have a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/portal-id-is-not-a-dom-element-wxw4yc)

Code in its entirety presented here. The console.log reports correctly that the element is a DOM element but React is throwing an error.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [portalDiv, setPortalDiv] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    let pd = document.getElementById("portalDiv");
    console.log(pd);
    setPortalDiv(pd);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="portalDiv">portal container</div>
      <div className="app">
        {/* {console.log("render portaldiv", portalDiv)} */}
        {
          (portalDiv &&
            createPortal(
              <>
                <h1>Inside portal</h1>
              </>
            ),
          portalDiv)
        }
        <h1>Outside portal</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You usecase doesnt make sense, why would u want to inject into the V-DOM? The portal intended to be injected into DOM. "Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component." Are you sure you actually want to do this? If so use React API - useRef, instead of querying via document object - so you wont have a race condition (thats what happens in this case).

Comment: I guess your mistake is in understanding whats "outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component" means, it means to inject into element in your HTML file, the `index.html` file where your "<div id="root"></div>" located, its intended to inject into other element than this root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usecase is not recommended as stated in my comment, but here is a reproducible example.

If you intend to inject a React Node into VDOM, you should use React API for that, so you won't get a race condition while querying the DOM via DOM API.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const containerRef = useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={containerRef}>portal container</div>
      <div id="app">
        {containerRef.current &&
          createPortal(<h1>Example Element</h1>, containerRef.current)}
        <h1>Outside portal</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit portal id is not a DOM element (forked)]

Comment: Thanks I think your example provides a solution but Im unsure why this is working and my example isn't. Im effectively doing the same thing using a DOM get function instead of a ref. ? Doesnt this example also contradict your previous advice about injecting into index.html outside the React component root? Im really trying to understand not catch you out. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to DM me on twitter I feel there is a gap in understanding so it will consume a lot of time filling it in comments.

Comment: Thank you so much I dont have a twitter account do you have another means of contact?I still cant see why you have effectively presented the same example using a ref and it works despite you suggesting it shouldnt. #confused.

Comment: I didnt say it shouldnt work, I said its not recommended use case, and its not "effectively doing the same thing" its actually NOT doing the same thing at all.

Comment: "If you intend to inject a React Node into VDOM, you should use React API for that, so you won't get a race condition while querying the DOM via DOM API". - missed that bit first time round I think thats what Ive been doing wrong. many thanks Dennis.